# phpdoc for inherited method

Tags: php, inheritance, phpdoc

I have class A with some method that returns bool value. I made phpdoc for that method.

I made another class B which extends class A and overrides method. New method returns string. 
(I understand that in common case change the return type is not a good idea, but in my case it's a good way.)

I want to make phpdoc for new method. I could use {@inheritDoc}, but it takes full phpdoc from old method. I want to take from old phpdoc general method description and specification of arguments, but change description of return value.

How could I do it?

Comment: Have a look at `{@see}`

Comment: Yes, I will use @see. Thank you )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the phpDocumentor manual for [inheritance](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/inheritance.html#methods) methods will inherit without the need for an inline `{@inheritDoc}` tag and you can override tags as you see fit.

> Inheritance for methods functions similar to classes and interfaces.
>   When a superclass of the current class contains a method with the same
>   name (hence, this method is re-defined) then the following information
>   is inherited from that overridden method:
>
> - Summary
> - Description
> - The following tags:
>
>   - author
>   - copyright
>   - version
>   - param
>   - return
>   - throws
>
> As with classes, each of the above will only be inherited if the
>   redefined method’s DocBlock does not have the element that is to be
>   inherited. So, for example, if the DocBlock of the redefined method
>   has a summary then it will not receive the overridden method’s
>   summary.

However from experience IDE's handle parsing this data in their own way and hence results may vary. For example, in IntelliJ/PHPStorm the parent method docs will be inherited but you can either override everything or nothing.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I read manual, but {@inheritDoc} didn't worked. That's because I use phpstorm... )) Thank you